# An exercise about convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convergence/divergence of $\sum\frac{a_n}{1+na_n}$ when $\sum a_n$ diverges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130471/convergence-divergence-of-sum-fraca-n1na-n-when-sum-a-n-diverges)

Let $a_n$ be a non-negative sequence such that the series $\sum a_n$ does not converge. Could the series $\sum a_n/(1+na_n)$ be convergent?

Comment: How big are the terms for which $a_n < 1/n$?  What about when $a_n \ge 1/n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Try $a_n=1$ if $n$ is a power of $2$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Assume all indices are positive for $\{ a_n \}$.

If $n$ is one less than a power of two, let $a_n = 1$. Else, let $a_n = 0$. Then the series $\sum a_n$ does not converge since the $i$-th partial sum is the number of numbers that are one less than a power of two and are less than or equal to $i$, and there are infinitely many positive numbers that are one less than a power of two.

On the other hand, $\sum a_n/(1 + na_n) = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + \cdots = \sum 2^{-n} = 1$.

Answer (score -1):

If $\sum a_n = \infty$, then there exist $n_0: n\ge n_0 \Rightarrow a_n \ge 1$. Hence,
\begin{equation}
\infty = \sum_{n\ge n_0} \dfrac{a_n}{a_n(n+1)} \le \sum_{ n \ge n_0}\dfrac{a_n}{(na_n+1)}.
\end{equation}
Then $\sum a_n/(1 + na_n)$ does not converge.

I messed up. My argument is if $\lim a_n=\infty$.

Comment: What if $a_n=\frac{1}{2}$ (or even $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$) for all $n$?