# Prove that if $\sum a_n$ is divergent then $\sum a_n/(1 + na_n)$ diverges too

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I had this question where it was given $$a_n > 0$$ and $$\sum a_n$$ is divergent and I was to prove that $$\sum\frac{a_n}{1 + na_n}$$ diverges too, to be frank I could not make any worthy headway on this problem, so any ideas ?

Comment: Isn't that the same? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130471/convergence-divergence-of-sum-fraca-n1na-n-when-a-n-geq0-and-sum-a-n?rq=1

Comment: Yeah it's the same one